# How does the Munq IocContainer dispose of registered objects within a lifetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am using [Munq](http://munq.codeplex.com/) as my IoC Container for an ASP.NET MVC3 project using the standard WebActivator that is provided in the NuGet package. Here is a sample registration:

```
ioc.Register<IUnitOfWork>(i =>
{
    return new UnitOfWork("Data Source=foo");
}).AsRequestSingleton();
```

How does Munq dispose of the IUnitOfWork object at the end of the request? I don't see any tests in the source on [codeplex](http://munq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) that would indicate that these are disposed!? 
[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Munq will not dispose anything. If you need this ability, it would be better to use a different IoC container, such as Autofac.

However, in many cases I doubt the real need for letting the container dispose objects for you. The unit of work is a good example, because your `IUnitOfWork` would have a `Commit()` method anyway, which is probably called in the application. The class that calls `Commit` is most likely responsible for the lifetime of the `IUnitOfWork` and therefore also for calling commit.

You can solve this by *not* injecting an `IUnitOfWork`, but injecting an `IUnitOfWorkFactory`. The class that needs a unit of work can than do the following:

```
using (IUnitOfWork unit = this.uowFactory.CreateNew())
{
    // Do some useful stuff.

    unit.Commit();
}
```

***UPDATE Dec 2012:***

My opinion about how to register Unit of Work instances has (partially) changed due to new insights and the way I design applications. Instead of injecting a factory, I currently like to inject an `IUnitOfWork` directly. This means that it would be good to dispose the unit of work when defined scope (such as a web request) ends. As @DaRKoN_ explained, since Munq 3.14 the RequestLifetime disposes instances.

This [Stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why) gives a thorough explanation about when and how to inject unit of works directly, instead of injecting factories.

Comment: Note that as of Munq 3.14: "Now disposes of IDisposable objects with RequestLifetime at the end of the HttpRequest."