# Calling commands from within another command Handle() method

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, dependency-injection, unit-of-work

Hi I am using the [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) DI library and have been following some really interesting material about an architectural model designed around the command pattern:

- [Meanwhile... on the command side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)
- [Meanwhile... on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)

The container will manage the lifetime of the `UnitOfWork`, and I am using commands to perform specific functions to the database.

My question is if I have a command, for example an `AddNewCustomerCommand`, which in turn performs another call to another service (i.e. sends a text message), from a design standpoint is this acceptable or should this be done at a higher level and if so how best to do this?

Example code is below:

```
public class AddNewBusinessUnitHandler
    : ICommandHandler<AddBusinessUnitCommand>
{
    private IUnitOfWork uow;
    private ICommandHandler<OtherServiceCommand> otherHandler;

    AddNewBusinessUnitHandler(IUnitOfWork uow, 
        ICommandHandler<OtherServiceCommand> otherHandler)
    {
        this.uow = uow;
        this.otherHandler = otherHandler;
    }

     public void Handle(AddBusinessUnitCommand command)
     {
        var businessUnit = new BusinessUnit()
        {
            Name = command.BusinessUnitName,
            Address = command.BusinessUnitAddress
        };

        var otherCommand = new OtherServiceCommand()
        {
            welcomePostTo = command.BusinessUnitName
        };

        uow.BusinessUnitRepository.Add(businessUnit);

        this.otherHandler.Handle(otherCommand);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It depends on your architectural view of (business) commands, but it is quite natural to have a one to one mapping between a [Use Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) and a command. In that case, the presentation layer should (during a single user action, such as a button click) do nothing more than create the command and execute it. Furthermore, it should do nothing more than execute that *single* command, never more. Everything needed to perform that use case, should be done by that command.

That said, sending text messages, writing to the database, doing complex calculations, communicating with web services, and everything else you need to operate the business' needs should be done during the context of that command (or perhaps queued to happen later). Not before, not after, since it is that command that represents the requirements, in a presentation agnostic way.

This doesn't mean that the command handler itself should do all this. It will be quite naturally to move much logic to other services where the handler depends on. So I can imagine your handler depending on a `ITextMessageSender` interface, for instance.

Another discussion is if command handlers should depend on other depend command handlers. When you look at use cases, it is not unlikely that big use cases consist of multiple smaller sub use cases, so in that sense it isn't strange. Again, there will be a one to one mapping between commands and use cases.

However, note that having a deep dependency graph of nested command handlers depending on each other, can complicate navigating through the code, so take a good look at this. It might be better to inject an `ITextMessageSender` instead of using an `ICommandHandler<SendTextMessageCommand>`, for instance.

Another downside of allowing handlers to nest, is that it makes doing infrastructural stuff a bit more complex. For instance, when wrapping command handlers with a decorator that add transactional behavior, you need to make sure that the nested handlers run in the same transaction as the outer most handler. I happened to help a client of me with this today. It's not incredibly hard, but takes a little time to figure out. The same holds for things like deadlock detection, since this also runs at the boundary of the transaction.

Besides, deadlock detection is an great example to show case the power of this command/handler pattern, since almost every other architectural style will make it impossible to plug-in this behavior. Take a look at the `DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator` class in [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)) to see an example.

Comment: So how do you prevent a command dispatched from a command handler from executing those deadlock or transaction decorators?

Comment: You will either have to prevent the decorators from getting applied to the nested handlers (which is typically really hard to achieve with any DI Container), or you let the decorator itself detect that it already runs in the context of a transaction. Another option is to give nested handlers their own abstraction. This makes it trivial to only apply decorators to the outer handler.