# Unity with HierarchicalLifetimeManager. Do I need a 'Using' Statement with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I am using `Unity` and Entity Framework in a Web API 2 application.  I register types with the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager.`

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Do I need to wrap all my dbContext calls in a using statement like this? Is this needed? I thought Unity will dispose the context for me.

```
using (var client = new dbContext())
{
     var result = client.Customers.toList();
}
```

Or can I just use dbContext without the `using` statement?

Comment: If you do `var client = new dbContext()`, Unity has nothing to do with the context's life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to wrap all my dbContext calls in a using statement like
>   this?

I would say that it depends on how you use your context. Take this example:

```
public class Service : IService, IDisposable
{
    private DbContext _context;
    public Service(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public object Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.Customers.Find(id);
    }

    public object Update(object obj)
    {
        // Code for updating
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you register `Service` with `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` the `context` will practially never be disposed, since nothing will dispose the service and thus never dispose the `context`. However, the example above should work fine with `TransientLifetimeManager`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx):

> **HierarchicalLifetimeManager**. For this lifetime manager, as for the
>   **ContainerControlledLifetimeManager**, Unity returns the same instance of
>   the registered type or object each time you call the Resolve or
>   ResolveAll method or when the dependency mechanism injects instances
>   into other classes.

If you instead dispose it in each method, then it will be correctly disposed regardless of what lifetimemanager you use. Also, the consumer of `IService` doesn't need to care about disposing `IService`.

```
public class Service : IService
{

    public object Get(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            return context.Customers.Find(id);
        }
    }

    public object Update(object obj)
    {
        // Code for updating
    }
}
```

Also, consider what happens *if* your `Service` was `Transient`, and is injected in a manager that is `ContainerController`. Since the manager never is disposed, neither is the service. The manager will keep the same instance of the service throughout the lifetime of the container. Therefore I **personally** suggest that you keep the disposing of the context outside of the containers control. **It can work very well** with the help of lifetimemanagers if you make sure that you have a chain of disposings. There are several posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926873/unitofwork-with-unity-and-entity-framework) and on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32071/entity-framework-using-repository-pattern-unit-of-work-and-unity-viable-appro) that show examples of UoW with Unity to dispose the context.