# Register RavenDb using Autofac?

Tags: ravendb, autofac

Can anyone guide me on how I could register RavenDB using Autofac?

`builder.Register<DocumentStore>(`.. what after that?

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940988/how-to-configure-simple-injector-ioc-to-use-ravendb. It talks about Simple Injector, but it would be pretty much the same for Autofac.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a sample console program that illustrates not only how to wire up the document store, but also how to set it up so you can just inject your document session:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Document;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

      // Register the document store as single instance,
      // initializing it on first use.
      builder.Register(x =>
        {
          var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" };
          store.Initialize();
          return store;
        })
           .As<IDocumentStore>()
           .SingleInstance();

      // Register the session, opening a new session per lifetime scope.
      builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession())
           .As<IDocumentSession>()
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
           .OnRelease(x =>
             {
               // When the scope is released, save changes
               //  before disposing the session.
               x.SaveChanges();
               x.Dispose();
             });

      // Register other services as you see fit
      builder.RegisterType<OrderService>().As<IOrderService>();

      var container = builder.Build();


      // Simulate some activity.  5 users are placing orders simultaneously.
      Parallel.For(0, 5, i =>
        {
          // Each user gets their own scope.  In the real world this would be
          // a new inbound call, such as a web request, and you would let an
          // autofac plugin create the scope rather than creating it manually.
          using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
          {
            // Let's do it.  Again, in the real world you would just inject
            // your service to something already wired up, like an MVC
            // controller.  Here, we will resolve the service manually.
            var orderService = scope.Resolve<IOrderService>();
            orderService.PlaceOrder();
          }
        });
    }
  }

  // Define the order service
  public interface IOrderService
  {
    void PlaceOrder();
  }

  public class OrderService : IOrderService
  {
    private readonly IDocumentSession _session;

    // Note how the session is being constructor injected
    public OrderService(IDocumentSession session)
    {
      _session = session;
    }

    public void PlaceOrder()
    {
      _session.Store(new Order { Description = "Stuff", Total = 100.00m });

      // we don't have to call .SaveChanges() here because we are doing it
      // globally for the lifetime scope of the session.
    }
  }

  // Just a sample of something to save into raven.
  public class Order
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Note that DocumentStore is single instance, but DocumentSession is instance per lifetime scope.  For this sample, I am manually creating the lifetime scopes and doing it in parallel, simulating how 5 different users might be placing orders at the same time.  They will each get their own session.

Putting SaveChanges in the OnRelease event is optional, but will save you from having to put it in every service.

In the real world, this might be a web application, or a service bus application, in which case your session should be scoped to either the single web request or the lifetime of the message, respectively.

If you are using ASP.Net WebApi, you should go get the Autofac.WebApi package off NuGet and use their .InstancePerApiRequest() method, which automatically creates the appropriate lifetime scope.