# IoC Task Scheduler Design with Simple Injector with code example recommendations

Tags: .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

Hi I am using [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/) and I am trying to implement a scheduler service which calls command(s) at a programmable regular frequency. My design decisions are below:

1) I have a service that runs a background thread and resolves from the container `ICommandHandler<SyncExternalDataCommand>.Handle(someParameter)` and calls the command handle method.

`RegisterCommandAsBusinessUnitCronJob` will be called for each BusinessUnit with the ID passed as a parameter on each call. We could also implement `RegistercommandAsCustomerContactCronJob` to loop through customer records.

**Is it ok to design the scheduler in this way with a background thread?**

2) I have tried to keep the coupling between the composition root container and the scheduler to a minimum.

An approach with Action helper delegates helps to keep the code in the composition root section as opposed to within the service. **By using a different design, could this coupling be reduced further or is this coupling acceptable?**

Code is below (it is yet to be made thread-safe), comments on the design decisions above and improvements/redesign are very welcome.

Thanks,
Chris

**Bootstrap of the container**

```cs
void Register(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterSingle<IUnitOfWorkFactory>(
        new UnitOfWorkFactory(container));
    container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    container.RegisterSingle<ILogger, Logger>();
    container.RegisterSingle<ICronJobService, CronJobService>();
    container.Register<ICommandHandler<SyncExternalDataCommand>, 
        SyncExternalDataCommandHandler>();

    var cronJobService = container.GetInstance<ICronJobService>();

    cronJobService.RegisterCommandAsBusinessUnitCronJob("* 1 * * *",
        (Int32 id) =>
        {
            var command = new SyncExternalDataCommand()
            {
                businessUnitId = id
            };

            using (container.BeginLifetimeScope()) 
            { 
                // handler must be resolved INSIDE the scope. 
                var handler =
         container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<SyncExternalDataCommand>>(); 
                handler.Handle(command); 
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**Scheduler service**

```cs
// to be instantiated as a singleton by IoC container
public class CronJobService : ICronJobService
{
    // this dictionary is for tasks that will be called with 
    // the business unit primary key (Int32).
    private cronJobs = new Dictionary<Action<Int32>, string>();

    public void RegisterCommandAsBusinessUnitCronJob(
        string cronString, Action<Int32> commandFactory)
    {
        cronJobs.Add(commandFactory, cronString);
    }

    // this below is called when we are running a task
    protected static bool RunCreateAndHandleThread(
        object parameter)
    {
        var jobParameters = (ThreadJobParameters)parameter;

        if (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // we will need to construct new graph with a
            // proxy command
            jobParameters.helper(jobParameters.businessUnitId);
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected static void SomeBackgroundLoop(
        RunHandlePollingLoopParameters parameters)
    {
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = 
            parameters.unitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork();

        using (unitOfWork)
        {
            var businessUnits = 
                unitOfWork.BusinessUnitRepository.Get();

            // loop through cron jobs and business units
            foreach (var helperFactory in parameters.cronJobs.Keys)
            {
                // its time to run this job...
                if (isTimeToRunCronjob) 
                {
                    var jobParameters = new ThreadJobParameters
                    {
                        helper = helperFactory,
                        businessUnitId = businessUnit.Id
                    };

                    Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(
                        RunCreateAndHandleThread, 
                        jobParameters, 
                        CronJobService.cancellationTokenSource.Token, 
                        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                        TaskScheduler.Default);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remember, the longer your question, the more unlikely that someone will take the time to study it. Could you shorten it to just the relevant bits?

Comment: one of the developers of Simple Injector is somewhere around here, perhaps he sees this :-)

Comment: @MareInfinitus: He is around here, but the question is a bit long :-( so I can't quickly answer the question. However, the question is rather general, and has little to do with the Simple Injector itself. So hopefully others can jump in as well.

Comment: Hi yes sorry for long post it has since been heavily edited and I have reduced it down to 2 questions, the second question is related to my now favourite IoC container specifically with the delegate `container.BeginLifetimeScope())`

The code is working, and coupling seems acceptable, but since I am new to this new way of thinking if i am doing anything shocking please let me know - if it seems acceptable and doesnt have too much code smell  then i am happy to run with it as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to design the scheduler in this way with a background thread?

Sure. As long as everything is thread-safe. From a DI perspective there is no problem, but of course you need to make sure that shared dependencies are thread-safe (as you must do with all multi-threaded applications). However, when the service is performant / fast enough without multi-threading, make the application single-threaded. This makes everything so much easier.

> By using a different design, could this coupling be reduced further or is this coupling acceptable?

Possibly. Your `CronJobService` takes a dependency on the `Container`. This is not a problem, as long as it is part of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). However, your `CronJobService` contains a lot of logic, which means you probably want to test it, but this is hard since you coupled it with the container and `Task.Factory`. Separate this if you can.

The use of a `IUnitOfWorkFactory` can be fine (take a look at [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why/10588594#10588594) for instance). But since you already have a `IUnitOfWork` registered Per Lifetime Scope, I don't really see how a `IUnitOfWorkFactory` helps. So instead of calling the `CreateUnitOfWork` inside the `SomeBackgroundLoop`, you can just wrap this method with a `using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())`. This way this method runs inside the context of a lifetime scope, which means that any injected `IUnitOfWork` (within this thread) will be the same unit of work.

Comment: again many thanks for your time and answers, SomeBackGroundLoop thread will spawn addititional threads, so for each thread a new object graph will need to be created in the new thread RunCreateAndHandleThread. Glad its seemingly on the right track, you should have seen my old service before i used IoC!