# EF5 Code First TransactionScope without escalating to MSDTC

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactionscope

I'm using EF5 code first, and I need to wrap multiple calls to `SaveChanges()` in the same transaction.  I'm relatively new to using transactionScope, and can't seem to tweak the options on it to accomplish what I'm looking to do.

The following code resides in a service class that gets injected with an instance of my DbContext class.  I do not create additional instances of DbContext anywhere in this class.

At first I tried the following.  The code is nice and clean, but it attempts to escalate to to DTC during the `SaveChanges` method in the `GenerateInvoice` function.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // This function does some work and calls SaveChanges
    Guid invoiceId = GenerateInvoice(cart);  

    // This function also does some querying and calls SaveChanges
    DeleteCart();

    // Transaction should only commit if both functions above were successful
    scope.Complete();

}
```

I did some research and changed the code to the following which does not escalate to DTC, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

```
IObjectContextAdapter adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)_context;

adapter.ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{

    // This function does some work and calls SaveChanges
    Guid invoiceId = GenerateInvoice(cart);  

    // This function also does some querying and calls SaveChanges
    DeleteCart();

    // Transaction should only commit if both functions above were successful
    scope.Complete();

    adapter.ObjectContext.Connection.Close();

}
```

Is there a simpler way to get transaction support with EF5 code first across multiple `SaveChanges` without escalating to DTC?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I have found.  And it makes sense as well.  By calling `SaveChanges()` more than once, you are potentially opening up multiple connections to the database.  The only way to coordinate the transaction across these connections is with a distributed transaction (hence MSDTC).

The best solution I could come up with was to only call `SaveChanges()` once.  This might mean restructuring some code, but it is best if all the entities that are needed to be transactional all commit at the same time.

Only calling `SaveChanges()` once also allows the EF change tracker to use its cache and save a lot of communication between the app and the db.

Comment: I agree, it does make sense.  `SaveChanges` opens and closes the connection itself.  I was just hoping there was a better answer :)  Restructuring is possible, but would result in duplicated code.  I have a DeleteCart method that deletes the cart.  This can be called by consumers of my service directly, but also internally at other times (there are many ways a cart can be deleted).

Comment: It might not mean duplicate code.  For example, if you are building a web application, there are patterns that will open up a dbcontext at the beginning of the request and then `SaveChanges()` at the end of the request.  Therefore, anything that happens inside the request is committed.  This is leaning towards more true persistence ignorance.

Comment: This is a good reference question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I can see how what you said could be used very nicely in the command / handler pattern.

Comment: Marked as answer because this led me to my answer which is to handle the transactions at a higher level.