# Entity framework not getting data (Maybe Unit of Work doesn't work)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have One to Many connection between message thread and messages. And I noticed smth. strange when I try to display messages for message thread.

For example there are 5 messages in thread (I've checked database and everything is as it should be) but my repository only fetches 3 messages form thread.

I've made some minor changes, run migration script, and this time repository managed to fetch all five messages.

So I've decided to add 2 more messages (and they've been added successfully) but this time repository fetched 5 messages and not 7.

So I've made new controller, this time repository fetched all 7 messages, again I added a few but it again fetched 7.

Why is that ? I suppose problem could be in my Unit of Work.

Here is code for UintOfWork: http://pastebin.com/kemDsy2C
Here is code where I fetch message thread: http://pastebin.com/D0QEhRbm
And finally here is code for controller: http://pastebin.com/G40cK3Gz

Any help i appreciated :)

Edit I forgot to mention that I create messages using signalR hub and calling repository same way i call it in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your classes (including UnitOfWork) are static. This is a big no no with Entity Framework. Change them from static and you'll be ok. Also consider using a Dependency Injection container to manage object lifetimes and to inject the instances you need into each controller.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why/10588594#10588594) for more information.