# Resolve using Unity Container

Tags: unity-container, containers

How do i resolve by passing a new instance of DbContext using Unity

```
 UnityContainer.RegisterType<ISpecificationRepository, SpecificationRepository>("DbContext", new InjectionConstructor(typeof(DbContext)));
```

Many Thanks

niju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't supply the container with instances when resolving stuff.

When dealing with runtime values the adviced way is to use a factory abstraction that contains the value.

In your case, the `DbContext` shouldn't be a runtime value, but should be configured in the container with a certain lifetime. Your application logic should not create and dispose the `DbContext`. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why) to learn more about the registration of DbContext instances in a DI container.