# Entity Framework DbContext UnitOfWork Repository IoC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container, ioc-container, ninject-2

Now I use UnitOfWork:

```
class UnitOfWork:DbContext,IUnitOfWork
{
....
}
```

I use it in my service classes in this maner:

```
using(var uow = new UnitOfWork)
{
     var service = new Service(uow,new Repository<SomeClass>(uow));
     service.DoSomething();

}
```

I want to inject UnitOfWork to service constructor.
And i make desctop app.
How to do it and how UnitOfWork would be disposed?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyService {

    Func<IUnitOfWork> _dbFunc;

    public MyService(Func<IUnitOfWork> makeDbFunc) {
        _dbFunc = makeDbFunc;
    }

    public void MyServiceCall(){

        using(var disposableDb = (IDisposable)_dbFunc()){
            // Do Work Here
        }
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
MyService service = new MyService(() => new UnitOfWork());
service.MyServiceCall();  // <- UnitOfWork is created inside this method
```

You still have to create a new IUnitOfWork in your service methods. But this is a way to inject the concrete type that you will use.

Comment: I want to use IoC how to implement this with DI and IoC(Uniti).

Comment: And how I can dispose UnitOfWork,wich was created by ioc - container?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why?lq=1 to understand the benefits and pitfalls of injecting the `UnitOfWork` with a container such as Unity.