# Display ForeignKey Information on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have been stuck on this problem for awhile now.
I am trying to get and display information from the foreign or primary table from another table.

For example, I have a person and pet table.

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    // rest of the fields here
}

public class Pet
{
    [DisplayName("Belongs to:")]
    public int person_id { get; set; }
    // Rest of the fields here
}
```

person_id is a foreign key.

This is my view

```
 @model SpamValley.Models.Pet

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Pet</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.pet_name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pet_name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pet_name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.pet_type)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pet_type)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pet_type)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person_id, "Person")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @if (Model == null || Model.person_id == 0)
            {
                Html.DropDownList("person_id", "Select the person this pet belongs to");
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(M => M.person_id);
            }
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person_id)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[DisplayName("Create")]
public ActionResult Create() { return Create_Get(0); }

public ActionResult Create_Get(int p_id)
{
    if (p_id == 0)
    {
        ViewBag.person_id = new SelectList(db.People, "id", "first_name");
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        // Person Ps = db.People.ToList().Single(Per => Per.id == p_id);
        // ViewBag.person_id = Ps.first_name + " " + Ps.last_name;

        Pet P = new Pet { id = p_id };
        return View(P);
    }
}
```

Now I know there are few things wrong with the code above but I am more worried about how to display information from the other table. For example: I want to display First Name of the person on Pets.Create View. I would also like to display Pets.Name on Person.Index View.

I can do this easily on SQL database but I am a little confused on mvc logic for this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the class Pet has a property called Person that returns the person who it belongs? And the Person class should has a property called Pets that contains all his pets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a collection property to `Person` to hold all that person's pets, and add a property to `Pet` to hold that pet's owner.

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    // rest of the fields here

    public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    [DisplayName("Belongs to:")]
    public int person_id { get; set; }
    // Rest of the fields here

    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Second, you will probably need to do some minor configuration using [Entity Framework's fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx).

Third, edit your view to take advantage of your new properties. For example, to show the name of a pet's owner:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Owner.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved one of my problems. By the way, I am not too sure of the MVC logic but is this the best way of reading from database? I have this private SpamValleyEntities db = new SpamValleyEntities();, which will connect to database but I feel like it's making a new connection on every request and could be slow. Are there anything like Thread/Connection Pool I could be doing to speed things up or is this how MVC work?

Comment: @JohnC1, MVC projects I've worked on haven't had a huge number of users, but I can say I've never had an issue with creating a new DbContext for every request. If you search StackOverflow, you should find lots of questions already on that topic (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why/10588594#10588594).