# DI for a Repository and Unit of Work pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Previously I have had parameterless repositories being injected into my MVC controllers:

`ProjectRepository` implementation:

```
public class ProjectRepository : EntityFrameworkRepository<Project>, IProjectRepository
{
    public ProjectRepository()
    { }
}
```

`UnityConfig.cs` dependency resolution:

```
container.RegisterType<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
```

MVC Controller:

```
private IProjectRepository _projectRepository { get; set; }

public ProjectController(IProjectRepository projectRepository)
{
    _projectRepository = projectRepository;
}
```

This worked great.

Now I have implemented a Unit of Work pattern into my repository classes so that I can commit transactional changes to data (especially when changes are being made to more than one repository).

The new `ProjectRepository` implementation accepts a `IUnitOfWork` in its constructor:

```
public class ProjectRepository : EntityFrameworkRepository<Project>, IProjectRepository
{
    public ProjectRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork): base(unitOfWork)
    { }
}
```

This means that multiple repositories can share the same `IUnitOfWork` and changes can be collectively committed using `UnitOfWork.SaveChanges()`.

**QUESTION:**

How do I now use dependency injection to instantiate the repository with an instance of IUnitOfWork?

```
public ProjectController(IProjectRepository projectRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _projectRepository = projectRepository;
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

There could also be more than one repository injected into the controller.  How can these all be instantiated with the same IUnitOfWork?

Comment: If you start doing that, you are drifting away from a CRUD application and the amount of logic in your controllers will increase. This is the time to start moving to a different pattern. Move the unit of work and repository to the business layer and inject an abstraction for executing business logic into your controller. In other words: hide the way the request is processed completely from the presentation layer. I suggest using the [command/handler pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: @Steven:  Essentially the repository code would actually sit inside a service class, so it would achieve that (the above code was just an example).  But I would be stuck with the exact same problem.  The `ProjectService` constructor would be injected with a `IProjectRepository` and an `IUnitOfWork`.  How can I ensure that the `IUnitOfWork` instance is then also injected into the `IProjectRepository` constructor?

Comment: There is no need to inject IUnitOfWork into the controller if you're already injecting it into your repository. Just register IUnitOfWork with your Container with a PerWebRequest lifestyle so that the same instance is used across all repositories for a single web request.

Comment: Sorry, what I said above is not true, because you must call IUnitOfWork.Commit() somewhere. This is why I also use command handlers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your `IUnitOfWork` instance, use `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, this will ensure every dependency of `IUnitOfWork` within a single `IUnityContainer.Resolve` gets provided the same instance.

For example:

```
public class SomeDependency
{

}

public class Service
{
    public Service(SomeDependency someDependency, SomeDependency someDependency2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(someDependency == someDependency2); 
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    using(var container = new UnityContainer())
    {
        container.RegisterType<SomeDependency>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
        container.Resolve<Service>();
    }
}
```

This will output `True` to the Console.

See the page for [Understanding Lifetime Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) for further details.