# How can I create a dbcontext using Unity and ensure it's only created once per request to MVC or Web API?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, unity-container

I am working on an MVC / Web API application. My code currently creates a DbContext like this in a UowBase class:

```
   protected void CreateDbContext()
    {
        DbContext = new MyContext();
    }
```

this class also has the following:

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (DbContext != null)
            {
                DbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I want to do this in Unity. How can I do it and ensure it's just created once?

I read that there were problems with doing it like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, MyCertContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

and then having this in the constructor. Can some explain which method would be better and if there are advantages to one method over the other?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why

Comment: @Steven The question is HOW not WHY.

Comment: @Aron: Yep, that's why this is just 'related', not a duplicate. Perhaps 'informative' would have been a better word :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Install-Package Unity.AspNet.WebAPI
Install-Package Unity.Mvc
```

Read the instructions on how you register the per-request scoping (last I checked the nuget script did that). Secondly, register your `DbContext` with a `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.

Comment: I updated your answer and changed the package ids to ids of packages that are published and supported by the MS Patterns & Practices team. Please revert my change if you think this is inappropriate.

Comment: I simply went to the first result in my nuget search. I guess its been too long since I've spelunked into the P&P team feeds.

Comment: It's not your fault. It took ages before the P&P team published official packages. Others tried to fill this gab.

Comment: Hi Aron, So you are saying it's not right for me to use the new PerRequestLifetimeManager().  I'm a bit confused about the different managers.

Comment: For most IOC containers, you would use a `PerRequestLifetimeManager` or something like that...`Unity` however doesn't...oh crap...it DIDN'T have one in version 2...sigh...Ok...With the P&P lib you want to use `PerRequestLifetimeManager`. Edited.