# Is using a singleton class for db context creation a good practice?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I want to create a Singleton Object for Database context creation. I am just curious if it good practice to use singleton context in mvc applications.

Can somebody describe the pros and cons for a singleton context object?

Comment: @jamesakadamingo - Brother the time you have invested in correcting my grammatical errors , I am really impressed , rather than this if you have answered my query it will be more helpful I think.
But ya thanks for pointing this Error, will keep in mind in future.

Comment: This question should not have been voted down in the first place.

Comment: @user1006544 not a deliberate act at editing your grammar! Just trying to help a user's question get answered when I don't have a moment to do it!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10585478/861716

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who needs singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons)

Answer (score 2):

`DbContext` is not thread safe which is a massive con for its use as a singleton object in a multithreaded usage environment such as ASP.NET MVC.  Multiple concurrent DB operations will result in a thrown exception and you would need to synchronize access to the singleton object to avoid such a scenario.  You would also need to worry about stale cached data over its lifetime and manage refreshing said data appropriately.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does answer the question, but I'll make it clearer

Comment: so it is not good to use singleton object , rather create new context every time for db interaction , is it correct?

Comment: not necessarily for every db interaction, but for a common thread of db interactions (in the case of ASP.NET MVC, that tends to be one context per request)

Answer (score 2):

As a clarification point, consider if your singleton needs to be per session request or app domain. If you limit the scope to a single session request, you could be ok having a single access point (factory) for your variable creation and keep that value alive through that session, but make sure to dispose it when the request is complete.

However, don't keep a single context value alive for the entire app domain (static variable) or even user session. The context remembers every object that it fetched (to support tracking updated fields/values). Eventually you would end up duplicating your database in memory, but only with the values from that server instance. If you have a farm, this would be compounded by stale data between the servers over time.

Answer (score 0):

It is really bad to use singleton DbContex. All changes will be check in each SaveChanges. When your DbContext have lived long enough, it will be verry slow.