# Transient vs per webrequest lifestyle, what constitutes a web request?

Tags: ninject, castle-windsor, autofac

What are the differences between these two life cycles?

Let's say my MVC controller is being supplied with an object that was configured as transient, then when someone visits a method in that controller a new instance is injected in the class constructor and then the method is called.

Each and every get/post to the controller is a new request, right?  If so, then I don't see any difference between the two.

Can someone explain / provide an example of when you would use one vs the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot fault your DI tool for failing to distinguish between cases it doesn't know. PerWebRequest scope is a scope that lasts from the beginnning of a webcall to the end of the webcall. Transient lives as long as you hold a reference to the resolved entity (usually the caller's lifetime).

Of course if the resolving entity has the same lifespan as the request you won't see any difference. A PerWebRequest lifespan lives from the beginning of a request to its end. A Transient lifespan lives according to reference held on it; if you need some logging completely dependent on the current webrequest you would set a PerWebRequest lifespan. The controller that handles the request would get a Transient lifespan since its work finished it wouldn't be needed anymore

Comment: So if I use perwebrequest, and my controller throws a fault and my fault handler used the same UOW, they each would have the same UOW?  I suppose that would make sense because the transient cycle would cause the fault handler to get a new UOW.  Correct?

Comment: If your FaultHandler has the same request PerWebRequest as the controller it will live with the same scope. If your FaultHandler lives with a transient lifestyle, it will live as long as its container has a reference on it. Usually you don't really have to manage multiple fault handlers on a request so that should be enough

Answer (score 6):

The difference between *Transient* and *Web Request* is negligible when registering your `Controller` types as *Transient*, since -as you said- each request gets its own `Controller` and only one controller instance for that type is resolved in that request.

Things start to get interesting when there's a dependency in the `Controller`'s object graph that is refered by multiple components. A good example for when this might happen is with a [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) (such as Entity Framework's `DbContext`). Multiple services inside the object graph might need that same Unit of Work, and for the correctness of your application they all need the same instance during that request; but each request must get a new Unit of Work instance.

To learn more about when and when not to have one Unit of Work *Per Request* or not, read this: 
[One DbContext per web request… why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why)

Comment: hi, I wonder, what happened when register my Controller as PerWebRequest but Services and component classed that used by controller is registered as Transient. Is removed from container when controller is release?