# Using InjectionFactory to inject DbContext, lifetime of created instance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 project with Unity as DI framework.

Consider the following code:

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

As my repositories are using the same DbContext, it would be practical to pass the same instance to all of them. However, every visitor of the site should have a separate instance of the context, not work on one big "site-wide" instance. I guess this reduces the possibilites to have an instance lifetime only for the current request.

As `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents()` is in the `Application_Start()` method, I guess it would only create one instance for the entire application.
What is the best practice in this case? I have thought about the following:

1. Create my own factory for the DbContext which returns a singleton, and inject this factory into my repositories
2. Move `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents()` to `Application_BeginRequest()`

I tried to search for InjectionFactory on Microsoft's site, not much luck (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionfactory%28v=pandp.51%29.aspx)

What best practice should I follow in this case? I don't want to overengineer it, what is the simplest working solution?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a web developer but reading through the book Dependency Injection With Unity they did mention a special lifetime manager that you can use for a single HTTP request - [PerRequestLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)

Perhaps that would work for your needs?

Comment: Thanks. Any example of this one tailored to my code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the factory and replace with:

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

This will result in an ApplicationDbContext instance per request and also take call of disposing of the context at the end of the request.

Answer (score -2):

I think what you're after is the unit of work pattern.

Take a look at the following link

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: It is summarised.  "Unit of work pattern".  It's a good article for what's needed and should be read regardless of what I take from it and summarise as you say.

Comment: Using a repository *inside* a unit of work is a really bad, bad idea. I've read that article a few times and it makes me want to bash my head into my desk. Here is a better article: http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: That article violates OCP.  You can't easily swap entity framework for something else.  Of course the repository implementation is tied to EF, it's an implementation of an interface, the idea is you can implement a new one, maybe nhibernate and then it's just resolved using ioc.

Comment: It's fairly rare that you would need to swap out one ORM for another in a single software project. If you need that added abstraction, then by all means, create a separate DAL which encapsulates the specifics of your database access logic. The point that Rob makes in the article, and I agree because I learned from the school of hard knocks, is that *every operation against your repository should be atomic*. Doing otherwise will lead you into a world of hurt. Moreover, I'm now of the mindset that repositories are business logic abstractions, not data layer.