# dbcontext is retrieving the old data and not updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I'm initializing dbContext in my controller as below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected KContext db;

    public BaseController()
    {
        db = new KContext();
    }
}
```

and I do the usual add,edit, delete stuff in my controllers, I also have a class called serviceChecker which inherits registry (from FluentScheduler), and I have another dbcontext initialized there as below:

```
public class ServiceChecker : Registry
{
    KContext db;
    public ServiceChecker()
    {
        db = new KContext();
    }
}
```

and I check some tables in this class and edit some entities which are also get updated from my controllers. Now the problem I'm facing is that after I change an entity, let's call it serviceDoman's field `endDate` from `7/11/2014` to `7/11/2016`, it updates the entity fine but when the `servicechecker` triggers the check function( every 60 sec), it has to update another field of that entity which happens fine but it also changes the `endDate` back to `7/11/2014`(old value before the first edit), what possibly could be the cause?

Comment: Why aren't you using one `DbContext` per request?

Comment: in my controller or servicechecker class? because in controller it works fine the problem happens in my servicechecker class

Comment: Why aren't you using one `DbContext` per request in both?

Comment: I'm quiet new to mvc concepts, could you please point me to the right direction about one DbContext per request? and could be the reason of my problem ?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/#q=mvc+dependency+injection

Comment: @arashmoeen see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why) for a great explanation of why one `DbContext` per request

Comment: @qujck Thanks for the link, I get it now, though I managed to fix the problem somehow I should give that link to the guy who implemented this :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason for getting old values after updating your entity is you are not calling `SaveChanges()` method to save entity changes and you are creating a new context object in `ServiceChecker` class which doesn't have any idea about the changes you made in an entity with your previous(another) context object.

One solution could be you call `SaveChanges()` method after you make changes in an entity.

**Note:** Its a good practice to use a common context object for performing all operations

Comment: Nah, I'm usign repository pattern here and I'm calling my save function which calls SaveChanges(), I also check the updated value done by controller and it's updated but exactly when the serviceChecker calls the check function it uses the old data, somehow like the dbcontext in my serviceChecker has not been updated or something like that... kinda lost here

Comment: could you please give me a tip about using a common context for both my BaseController and my ServiceChecker? thanks in advance

Comment: Create a `Base` or `AbstractRepository` in which you create your context or `DbContext` object and inherit other repository from that Base repository, by doing this you will have created only one context object in your application. I'd suggest you to use a `DbContext` object.

Comment: I already have a base repository which takes the initialized dbcontext .basically I initialize the dbcontext in my controller or my ServiceChecker and then pass it to each repository and they are all inherit from my base repository. I know this concept is not the best, it was implemented by another guy and I'm forced to just fix the problmes

Comment: Just use dependency injection and let some container manage the lifecycle of your `DbContext`.