# Unity PerRequestLifetimeManager SaveChanges

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have set up Unity Bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC and registered my database context (RavenDb in my case but it doesn't matter) with PerRequestLifetimeManager. At the end of request I want to call myContext.SaveChanges. Here is how I did it in NInject:

```
kernel.Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToProvider<DocumentSessionProvider>().InRequestScope().OnDeactivation(c => c.SaveChanges());
```

What is the right way to do this in Unity? The only way I see now is to override EndRequest in Global.asax but it seems a bit dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do NOT automatically call `SaveChanges` on the end of the request, because at that point of time it is not possible to safely determine whether or not changes should actually be saved or not. Read [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why) for more information.