# Autofac dependency injection in implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, owin, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I am creating a Web Api application and I want to use bearer tokens for the user authentication.
I implemented the token logic, following [this post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and everything seems to work fine. 
NOTE: I am not using the ASP.NET Identity Provider. Instead I have created a custom User entity and services for it.

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var container = DependancyConfig.Register();
        var dependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}
```

and this is my implementation of the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider class

```
private IUserService _userService;
    public IUserService UserService
    {
        get { return (IUserService)(_userService ?? GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IUserService))); }
        set { _userService = value; }
    }

    public async override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var user = await UserService.GetUserByEmailAndPassword(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

After I call the /token url, I receive the following error

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself

Is there a way to use dependency injection inside this class? I am using a repository pattern to access my entities, so I don't think that it is a good idea to make a new instance of the object context. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I have the same problem, and am unable to...thanks.

Comment: @shenku: I've added a response with what worked for me. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 19):

I have had a similar problem.

The problem here is that when you try to inject `IUserService` in your provider, Autofac detects that it has been registered as `InstancePerRequest` (that uses the well-known lifetime scope tag `'AutofacWebRequest'`) but the `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` is registered in the `'root'` container scope where the `'AutofacWebRequest'` scope is not visible.

A proposed solution is to register dependencies as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. This apparently solved the problem but introduces new ones. All dependencies are registered in the `'root'` scope, that implies having the same `DbContext` and services instances for all the requests. [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) explains very good in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588594) why is not a good idea to share the `DbContext` between requests.

After deeper investigation tasks, I've solved the problem getting the `'AutofacWebRequest'` from the `OwinContext` in the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class and resolving the services dependencies from it, instead of letting Autofac to inject them automatically. For this I've used the `OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope()` extension method from `Autofac.Integration.Owin`, see example below:

```
using Autofac.Integration.Owin;
...
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    ...
    // autofacLifetimeScope is 'AutofacWebRequest'
    var autofacLifetimeScope = OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(context.OwinContext);
    var userService = autofacLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserService>();
    ...
}
```

I've made `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` registration and injection inside `ConfigureOAuth` method in a similar way than proposed by [Laurentiu Stamate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5032761/laurentiu-stamate) in [another response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300838/2054754) to this question, as `SingleInstance()`.
I've implemented `RefreshTokenProvider` in the same way.

**EDIT**

@BramVandenbussche, this is my `Configuration` method in the `Startup` class, where you can see the order of middlewares added to the OWIN pipeline:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure Autofac
    var container = ConfigureAutofac(app);

    // Configure CORS
    ConfigureCors(app);

    // Configure Auth
    ConfigureAuth(app, container);

    // Configure Web Api
    ConfigureWebApi(app, container);
}
```

Comment: OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope returns null for me, was there anything else you set up ?

Comment: @BramVandenbussche, was your project working before changes for calling this method?

Comment: @BramVandenbussche, are you calling `app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container)`? As indicated by Alex Meyer-Gleaves in one of his [posts](http://alexmg.com/owin-support-for-the-web-api-2-and-mvc-5-integrations-in-autofac/): "This is required because along with enabling the middleware DI support, **this is also responsible for placing the lifetime scope in the OWIN context**".

Comment: Thx for the reply. I did perform the call to `app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container)` but the article you linked me too helped me figure out that I called it too late. I had to move that line BEFORE the setup of the OAuth and that fixed that problem. I'm now stuck with a `A delegate registered to create instances of 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' returned null` exception, but that's because there is no CurrentContext in the case of a `/token` call.

Comment: @BramVandenbussche, see my `Configuration()` method in the `Startup` class, where you can see the order of middlewares added to the OWIN pipeline. As I cannot add format code in the comment, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thx for the clarification. For future visitors & reference it might be useful if you were to include the import bits of the `ConfigureAutofac` `ConfigureAuth` and `ConfigureWebApi` methods, so that it's clear exactly which calls are being made.

Comment: @BramVandenbussche, those are my methods declared in `Startup` class where I configure each middleware. Please let me know if you need more details. Anyway, I will try to upload my project to github, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 12):

To use dependency injection in `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` you have to register `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` to the Autofac container just like any other type. You can do something like this:

```
builder
  .RegisterType<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>()
  .As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
  .PropertiesAutowired() // to automatically resolve IUserService
  .SingleInstance(); // you only need one instance of this provider
```

You also need to pass the container to the `ConfigureOAuth` method and let Autofac resolve your instance like this:

```
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = container.Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
};
```

You should always use single instances if your properties within the object don't change via external data (let's say you have a property which you set in the controller which dependents upon some information stored in the database - in this case you should use InstancePerRequest).

Comment: then you can use

`private readonly IAuthService _authService;

public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(IAuthService authService){ 

_authService = authService; 

}`

Comment: @ShalomDahan Have a look at this page: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/

Answer (score 3):

I also tried @jumuro answer using the OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope that saves my day. Instead of registering the IUserService at runtime, this answer gives an option on validation/creating the instance service after request.

I added some new answer because I can't comment yet because of my low reputations but added additional guide codes to help someone.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        try
        {
            if (service == null)
            {
                var scope = Autofac.Integration.Owin.OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(context.OwinContext);
                service = scope.Resolve<IUserService>();
            }
            var user = await service.FindUserAsync(context.UserName);
            if (user?.HashedPassword != Helpers.CustomPasswordHasher.GetHashedPassword(context.Password, user?.Salt))
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(context.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);

    }
```