# RequestContext Principal always null

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I have created a token .NET web API endpoint to get an OAuth bearer token. After retriving the token I call another endpoint of my API and I pass in the authorize header my bearer token but if I check the principal in the RequestContext it is always null. Why my owin server doesn't create a principal object.

Is it right to register my authorization provider like this:

```
 builder.RegisterType<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>()
            .As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
            .PropertiesAutowired()
            .SingleInstance();
```

Or should it be .InstancePerRequest(). But if I use the instance per request I receive an error. Has anyone a working example for this use case.
I am very desperately because I have tried multiple example but without resolution. This is even my second thread ([Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2 and Owin throws 401 unautorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440117/token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-and-owin-throws-401-unautoriz/40486983?noredirect=1#comment68351203_40486983)) on this problem but I think my problem resides on autofac because it's the only difference to other working samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solves my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769653/5441093

Change in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method this to resolve my userbl class:

```
var autofacLifetimeScope = OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(context.OwinContext);
        var userBl = autofacLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserBl>();
```

instead of using the injection of autofac