# If I pass a database context from a controller to a class, will the context be disposed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and at the bottom of my controller is the standard Dispose method that disposes the db context automatically for you.  I need to pass the db context from this controller to a service class for use to access the database from that class.

My questions is, if I pass the db context to this service class, will the automatic dispose method in my controller still dispose of this db context?

Comment: See the discussion here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472159/proper-way-to-use-dbcontext-global-or-pass-as-parameter