# How to solve the Simple Injector error "the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope" in WPF with MVVM?

Tags: wpf, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have application written in WPF and MVVM and I've used Simple Injector as IoC Container. My main view model has constructor in that I inject bll class:

```cs
public MainWindowViewModel(IReviewBodyBLL reviewBodyBLL)
{
    this.reviewBodyBLL = reviewBodyBLL;
```

and this view model is setup in MainWindow:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        base.DataContext = viewModel;
```

and all classes are registered:

```cs
container.Register<IFreewayReviewCreatorDbContext, FreewayReviewCreatorDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IUnitOfWorkFactory, UnitOfWorkFactory>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IReviewBodyBLL, ReviewBodyBLL>(Lifestyle.Transient);

// Register your windows and view models:
container.Register<MainWindow>();
container.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();
```

and I get error when I try to run application:

> Exception thrown: 'SimpleInjector.ActivationException' in SimpleInjector.dll
>
> The program '[28028] FreewayReviewCreator.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Application stop without any break.

When I remove from main view model constructor `IReviewBodyBLL reviewBodyBLL` application start correctly. How to inject bll to the constructor?

Comment: Please post the full exception details, i.e. exception type, exception message, and stack trace of the exception and *all* its inner exceptions.

Comment: Where and how are you instantiating the `MainWindowViewModel`?

Comment: MainWindowViewModel is instantiating in the constructor public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)

Comment: I have only this one error that I get in Output in VS

Comment: @Steven: UnitOfWorkFactory is registered using the 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope. I have changed Scope to Transient for UnitOfWorkFactory because it isn't disposable and now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a WPF application, where you can have multiple windows open at the same time, where each window should run in its own scope, Simple Injector's [ambient scoping model](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#scoped-lifestyle) will not work, because it becomes unclear when to dispose a single scope, as there will typically always be a window open.

Instead, you can use Simple Injector's "flowing" scoping model, as described in [this Q/A about Win Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641442/creating-custom-simple-injector-scope-in-web-forms). This will work the same for WPF.