# properly call EF SaveChanges after each request with Autofac managing scope

Tags: entity-framework, owin, autofac, middleware

I would like to put in a bit of infrastructure on my project to `SaveChanges` on my db context at the end of every request.

So I create a simple piece of Owin middleware

```
app.Use(async (ctx, req) => {
     await req();
     var db = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MyDbContext>();
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
});
```

This does not work and throws the error

> Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed.

If I resolve the db *before* completing the request

```
app.Use(async (ctx, req) => {
     var db = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MyDbContext>();
     await req();
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
});
```

It doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't work (as in changes aren't saved to the db and viewing db in the debugger shows the `DbSet`'s `Local` property throwing an `InvalidOperationException` about it being disposed.

I've tried with and without async, registering the middleware before and after autofac configuration (`app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container)`) and resolving the `LifetimeScope` directly from the Owin environment. All give me the same results.

I've done something like this before with Structuremap, but can't seem to figure the correct way to get Autofac to play nice.

Comment: How did you register your context ? using `InstancePerLifetimeScope` or `InstancePerRequest` ?

Comment: Calling `SaveChanges` at that point in the request is a bad idea. Please read [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why). To quote the answer: "... at the end of the request. Many people however, incorrectly assume that this is also the place to Commit the unit of work. However, at that point in the application, you simply can't determine for sure that the unit of work should actually be committed. e.g. If the business layer code threw an exception that was caught higher up the callstack, you definitely don't want to Commit.".

Comment: @CyrilDurand `b.RegisterType<AppleHmsContext>().InstancePerRequest();` @Steven I appreciate the intricacies and the above is a simplification of what I want to do. Thanks for the discussion though.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer it works on my machine. My code sample is here : http://pastebin.com/bSz8qnQ0

Comment: Hmm @CyrilDurand is that running via `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` or as a console Owin application?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer nop. I try again and instead of using `DependencyResolver.Current` I used `ctx.GetAutofacLifetimeScope()` and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steven is right about the fact that you should not be committing on the request disposal because you cannot be sure if you really want to commit there, unless you abstract your UoW from DbContext and keep a success attribute there, checking if on disposal and conditionally commit.

For your specific question, there are two things to clarify.

1. DbContext or UoW need to be registered with InstancePerRequest()
2. Instead of using Owin middleware, you should use OnRelease(context => context.SaveMyChangesIfEverythingIsOk()) native Autofac API

For example, this is how it would look like for RavenDb

```
   builder.Register(x =>
        {
            var session = x.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenAsyncSession();
            session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
            return session;
        })
            .As<IAsyncDocumentSession>()
            .InstancePerRequest()
            .OnRelease(x =>
            {
                x.SaveChangesAsync();
                x.Dispose();
            });
```

Comment: I see. Thanks Alexey. Do you know why that wouldn't work with Owin? presumably, if I register my middleware after the Autofac middleware it will get a chance to deal with the db before Autofac has a chance to dispose of it. Is this one of those weird things when using Owin with IIS?

Comment: I would in any case assume since Autofac is responsible for the dependency lifecycle, let it do this. Autofact is tracking when a request starts and ends and disposes the resolves/disposes dependencies accordingly. If you are registering some middleware, it has nothing to do with the container and the moment of disposal is not guaranteed. OnRelease is the native Autofac API and I would use that instead. You also will have no dependency on Owin since you might want to change it later to something like K.

Comment: I'm far more likely to want to change Autofac than Owin :)

Comment: AFAIK for ASP.NET vNext you will have to rewrite the middleware, however Autofac support will be more native thanks to BYOC strategy. Microsoft even implemented the first Autofac adapter for vNext themselves (being now replaced by the Autofac own adapter). So, I would argue about this. Also, I personally used ServiceStack on System.Net.Http and it was perfectly OK until I needed SignalR, I just installed Owin and SignalR but not really use its features but everything still works thanks to Autofac DI.