# Lifestyle Mismatch Web Request depends on Transient in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using simple injector with nuget in asp.net mvc 5

```
Install-Package SimpleInjector -Version 3.1.5
Install-Package SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc -Version 3.1.5
```

In global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //removed for bravity
           // Container container = new DependencyInjectionContiner().DI();
            var container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
            container.Register<IHomeRepository, HomeRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

            //For WebApi Request
           // container.Register<IWebApi, WebApi>(Lifestyle.Transient);
            container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            ////To verify life styles of injection
            container.Verify();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
                new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
        }
```

I showed error on

```
The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:

-[Lifestyle Mismatch] HomeRepository (Web Request) depends on UnitOfWork (Transient).
```

**IHomeRepository**

```
public interface IHomeRepository
    {
        void InsertDepartment(Department department, List<Student> students);
    }
```

**HomeRepository**

```
public class HomeRepository : IHomeRepository
    {
        private UnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        public HomeRepository(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public void InsertDepartment(Department department, List<Student> students)
        {
            department.Students = students;
            unitOfWork.DepartmentRepository.Insert(department);
            unitOfWork.Save();
        }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
        private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
        private GenericRepository<Student> studentRepository;

        public GenericRepository<Department> DepartmentRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.departmentRepository == null)
                {
                    this.departmentRepository = new GenericRepository<Department>(context);
                }
                return departmentRepository;
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<Student> StudentRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.studentRepository == null)
                {
                    this.studentRepository = new GenericRepository<Student>(context);
                }
                return studentRepository;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

**GenericRepository**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal SchoolContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        //public IQueryable GetIQueryable()
        //{
        //    return context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
        //}
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter);
        }
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Query()
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        //public IQueryable Query()
        //{
        //    return context.Set<TEntity>();
        //}
        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

why verify shows the error? and Is it ok to use  **Transient** and **Scoped** on a single container ????

Comment: The exception message contains this link https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics to the documentation. Did you read that documentation? Do you have any questions after reading this documentation and especially [this](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LifestyleMismatches.html)?

Comment: You mean to say make use of Hybrid Life style ? If so how to define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message refers to the following documentation page: https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics. The documentation states the following about Lifestyle Mismatches:

> In general, components should only depend on other components that are configured to live at least as long. In other words, it is safe for a transient component to depend on a singleton, but not the other way around. Since components store a reference to their dependencies in (private) instance fields, those dependencies are kept alive for the lifetime of that component. This means that dependencies that are configured with a shorter lifetime than their consumer, accidentally live longer than intended. This can lead to all sorts of bugs, such as hard to debug multi-threading issues.

The documentation also provides the following suggestions for fixes:

> - Change the lifestyle of the component to a lifestyle that is as short or shorter than that of the dependency.
> - Change the lifestyle of the dependency to a lifestyle as long or longer than that of the component.

This means you should either make the `HomeRepository` Transient, or make the `UnitOfWork` Scoped.

Making the `UnitOfWork` Scoped is the most obvious as discussed in [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why).

> You mean to say make use of Hybrid Life style

You should forget about hybrid lifestyles. They don't provide an answer to your problem.

Comment: One question ? It is ok to use WebRequestLife cycle or Transient Lifestyle for my Repository ? As i understand Transient can be memory consuming in IIS app pool

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash: Where did you learn the transient can be memory consuming? An ASP.NET application spits out a lot of memory, the creation of a few extra repositories will be unnoticable for performance. Your `HomeRepository` will be 20 bytes in size. Typically nothing to worry about.

Comment: So are u suggesting to stick to `Transient` by the way , i just like your answer .Thanks man

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash: No, what I'm suggesting is that you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why) carefully and make an educated decision whether it is okay for your `UnitOfWork` to be Transient or not, and act accordingly.