# Simple Injector - Lifestyle Mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using unit of work pattern for my transitions. I created an DbContext which is handling connection, commit, rollback works.

In my data access and business layer classes, I inject IDbContext by constructors.

```
public TestDAL(IDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) {}

public TestService(IDbContext dbContext, ITestDAL testDAL) {}
```

I moved simple injector from autofac. I'm getting an exception about lifestyle mismatch.

> -[Lifestyle Mismatch] TestService (Async Scoped) depends on IDbContext implemented by DbContext (Transient).
>
> -[Lifestyle Mismatch] TestDAL (Async Scoped) depends on IDbContext implemented by DbContext (Transient).

I register my DAL and Service classes as scoped and DbContext as transient.

```
var ServiceRegistrations =
                from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where type.Name.EndsWith("Service") && type.IsClass
                from service in type.GetInterfaces()
                select new { service, type };

foreach (var reg in ServiceRegistrations)
{
    container.Register(reg.service, reg.type, Lifestyle.Scoped);
}

container.Register<IDbContext, DbContext>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

I read some about DbContext should be transient, it is not thread safe. Also I think DAL and Service classes not necessary to create transient. How can I fix this situation? Btw, that was not problem at autofac.

Comment: Change your DbContext to Scoped. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why

Comment: @Steven thank you.