# What is the best practice for creating dbcontext (EF core) if the parent object is a singleton?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, botframework, dbcontext

I use [Virtual Assistant](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/overview/virtualassistant/). I am going to use Entity Framework Core for saving state. I met a problem. IStorage interface injects like a singleton because other objects which use this interface injects as a singleton.

```
        services.AddSingleton<IStorage>(new MyDbStorage()); //<-- my storage with dbcontext
        services.AddSingleton<UserState>();          //This class has ctor with IStorage param
        services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();  //And this class has ctor with IStorage param
        services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {
            var userState = sp.GetService<UserState>();
            var conversationState = sp.GetService<ConversationState>();
            return new BotStateSet(userState, conversationState);
        });
```

See on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Startup.cs#L82) for details.
I know, [the global dbcontext is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588594/989462).
Could you suggest me some options for creating dbcontext? 
I think about DbContextFactory, but I don't know how exactly create it.

**UPDATE**
I have updated code. See the first line.

Comment: So why can't you simply add is as `.AddTransient<IStorage>` ? Others might be singletons but this one - transient. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Fabjan, UserState is a singleton. It means that ctor will executes only one time. As you know, UserState ctor has param IStorage. UserState object will not be recreated in next requests or whatever. It means it doesn't matter that IStorage will be like a transient. In this case, a transient is the same as a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not abstract `MyDbContext` with interface, otherwise you won't be able to access EF fetures or will try hard to hide `EntityFramework` namespace. Use [AddDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) extension. This way `DbContext` will be registered as `Scoped` what is the best lifetime for it.

Inject `IServiceProvider` into your singleton `UserState` and `ConversationState`, then create scope and resolve `MyDbContext` instance within this scope **on demand only**.

```
public class UserState
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public UserState(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        using (var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
        using (var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>())
        {
            // do work
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**But** if work done by `UserState` and `ConversationState` should be performed as single transaction (that's mean on same `DbContext` instance), it's better to resolve `MyDbContext` in `BotStateSet` and pass in as argument into methods of `UserState` and `ConversationState`.

I'm not familiar with Virtual Assistant, but if it possible to use `Transient` lifetime for your state classes (at least for `UserState` and `ConversationState`) it will allow you to inject `MyDbContext` into constructor avoiding passing it as argument.

Comment: Ok, when reading the code again they are using `CosmosDbStorage` and not `DbContext`, so it's ok. But the whole code looks me ugly and I asked myself "why?" almost on each line of code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't edit BotStateSet. It is inside Microsoft.Bot.Builder namespace.