# How to instantiate DBContext in second thread?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, parallel-processing

I have recently stumbled across the fact that I cannot use the same instance of DBContext in separate threads. I have two services that share the same DBContext so I end up with an Exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this
> context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused
> by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more
> information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
> [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.'](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.%27)

So my code is mostly generated by ASP.Net core wizard

// program.cs

```
private static void ConfigureServices(string settings, IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<MMCC.Terminal.Service.Data.TerminalDbContext>((provider, options) =>
{                options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString(nameof(TerminalDbContext)));
});
}

 public MyService1(TerminalDbContext dbTerminal)
        {
            _dbTerminal     = dbTerminal;
        }

 public MyService2(TerminalDbContext dbTerminal)
        {
            _dbTerminal     = dbTerminal;
        }
```

Usage

```
void Run()
{
    _hourTimer  = new Timer(UpdateOnceInHour, null, 0, 60 * 60 * 1000);
    _minuteTimer = new Timer(UpdateEveryMinute,  null, 0,  1 * 60 * 1000);
}

private async void UpdateOnceInHour(object state)
{
 _mService1.DoSomething()
}

private async void UpdateOnceInHour(object state)
{
 _mService2.DoSomething()
}
```

So here is when I have an exception.

```
    // Service 1 
// thread 1
    private DoSomething()
    {
      await _dbTerminal.SomeTable1.ToListAsync();
    }
    
    // Service 2
// thread 2
    private DoSomething()
    {
      await _dbTerminal.SomeTable2.ToListAsync();
    }
```

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem. Is there any standard pattern? I tried refactoring my code, and instead of injecting TerminalDbContext into Service1, Service2 I do inject *IServiceProvider*, and then do *GetService* for *TerminalDbContext* but it seems that I end up with the same instance of DBContext.

Comment: I have struggled with the same problem of using my DbContext all the time at the beginning. :-)

Comment: You can specify the life time in [AddDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext), like `serrvices.AddDbContext<TerminalDbContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(...), ServiceLifetime.Transient)`.

Comment: `Transient` : Specifies that a new instance of the service will be created every time it is requested.

Comment: I would be tempted to pass each service a brand new instance of dbContext when invoking `DoSomething()` this is probably closer to it's intended, short-lived, usage.

Comment: @Vernou This comes with a whole bunch of implications regarding disposal and/or savechanges that are dealt with in a more cohesive fashion when using scoped lifetime. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588594/14357) (creating a factory) seems like best way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able use a using statement everywhere you need a unique instance and instantiate a new context that will be disposed when it is done.

```
using (var newContext = new TerminalDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TerminalDbContext>()
{
    // Define options
}))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: TerminalContext does not have parameterless constructor >>>>         public TerminalDbContext(DbContextOptions<TerminalDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

Comment: @CaptainComic See if this works for you.  I don't have as much experience in Core and don't use DbContextOptions.